# Transform Vertical data to Horizontal, with 60 Reg / Line

Tags: db2, db2-400

From this table,

```
Name  surname  Phone
Name1 Sur1     Myphone1
Name2 Sur2     Myphone2
Name3 Sur3     Myphone3
Name4 Sur4     Myphone4
...
Name100 Sur100  Myphone100
```

I would like to have to select in that ways , with Lines of 60 Registers horizontally.

```
Name1Sur1Myphone1, ... Name60Sur60Myphone60
Name61Sur61Myphone61, ... Name100Sur100Myphone100
```

Someone has an idea of how I can do this ?
Thank You -

Comment: So you want the "first" 60 records returned as 60 columns in the first row, the next 60 records as the next row?  How is "first" 60 determined?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH 
  MYTAB (RN_, Name, surname, Phone) AS
(
  VALUES (1, 'Name1', 'Sur1', 'Myphone1')
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 
     RN_ + 1
  , 'Name'    || TRIM (CHAR (RN_+1)) 
  , 'Sur'     || TRIM (CHAR (RN_+1))
  , 'Myphone' || TRIM (CHAR (RN_+1))
  FROM MYTAB
  WHERE RN_ < 100
)
*/
SELECT LISTAGG (Name || surname || Phone, ',')  
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER () AS RN_, Name, surname, Phone
FROM MYTAB
) T
GROUP BY (RN_ - 1) / 60
ORDER BY (RN_ - 1) / 60
```